# loop through array of dom objects and find first that match

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I have a navigation bar at the top of my eform that skips to the next and previous div (page/section) but only if that div is visible. The divs are hidden unless activated with a checkbox. so the next button on the nav bar needs to work by always taking you to the next available div.

The following code works for the first button but these nav bars display at the top of each section so the next section has a next button on it running the same function (which doesn't work) i'm struggling to exlpain myself here so please shout if i'm not making sense. Here's my code.

```
function showNext(){

    var pages = [document.getElementById("page2"),document.getElementById("page3")];
    var next = ["page2marker","page3marker"];

    for (var i=0; i<pages.length; i++){
        if(pages[i].style.display == "block"){
            window.location.hash = next[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Can i amend this function so that it will work for all buttons. I.e by always navigating to the next available div that is visible? I think i've probably missed a trick and a whole load of info but see what you think, any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: Would letting pages and next be parameters help to make this function more dynamic and thus be useful in other sections? You could then either change the parameters everywhere or create a wrapper function per section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using jQuery with the `jQuery.next` function - http://api.jquery.com/next/.

For a set of html like this:

```
<nav><a class="showNext">Show Next</a></nav>
<div class="content" style="display:none">I'm hidden</div>
<div class="content">I'm Visible</div>
```

You could use something like:

```
$('.showNext').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.hash = $(this).next('.content:visible').attr('id') + 'marker';
});
```